# Windows 8 Button click programmatically in C# and Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-8, .net-4.5

I want to click button programatically in C# xaml. As I found that there is no method like PerformClick. What else is the alternative for it.

Actually I have set of 10 buttons with x:Name like btn1, btn2, btn3 etc...
I have a number from 1 to 10 based on that number I need to click these buttons. I was planning to get the control by using

```
ParentControl.FindName('btn' + number)
```

and then fire the event from that. But since there is no PerformClick method in Windows 8 C# hence i need an alternative for this.

Raiseevent
[image]

Comment: Are buttons bound to `ICommand` instances?

Comment: No buttons are not bound to ICommand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to do it...

Let's say you have this button defined in your `XAML` file:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="DefaultSnooze" Content="Default Snooze" Click="SendToast_Click" Height="34" Width="134"/>
```

Then do this in your code behind where you want the `Click` event handler code to be fired programmatically:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(DefaultSnooze);

IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

I tested it right now and it works beautifully. :)

---

Source: [How to programmatically click a button](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/09/how-to-programmatically-click-a-button/)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use:

```
RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, myButton));
```

In the code-behind of a XAML view.

`RaiseEvent` is available on any UIElement-derived class.

Comment: I tried to use that but these is no method in UIElement in raise event. Please look to the above snapshot

Comment: @BalrajSingh No no, it's not a static method. Try simply using "RaiseEvent", it should be there.

Comment: I have tried to find that event. Can you please tell me where exactly can i find it. Since WinRT framework new for me. I tried but not able to find.

Comment: Well it seems to be present in .NET 4.5: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent.aspx)

Comment: Can you just tell me how to use it as I have also seen that its present in .Net4.5 but in my Windows8 App i am not able to get any way to use it.

Comment: Paste the code of the class where you want to raise the event.