# how do I call an event when text box filled with 10 digits in window phone app8?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In my application whenever the text box filled with 10 digits number an event need to be called and call service immediatly. please tell me how to get this.

```
 private async void txt1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new Appdatabase.JsonWebClient();

            var resp = await client.DoRequestAsync(Url.weburl + "GET_OperatorCircles?Phoneno=" + txt1.Text + "&servicetypeID=1");

            string result = resp.ReadToEnd();

            JArray jarray = JArray.Parse(result);

        }
```

Comment: [What have yo tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [show us your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am new to windows phone and c#  development .so could you please give  view to me

Comment: whenever enter 10 digits in textbox then event will occur without click button .what event will occurre in textbox please help me.

Comment: Should it be an event or a method?

Answer (score 0):

So try this, this is just a sample:

```
if(yourtextboxname.MaxLength == 10){

// Create a ButtonAutomationPeer using the ClickButton

 ButtonAutomationPeer buttonAutoPeer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(ClickButton);

// Create an InvokeProvider

IInvokeProvider invokeProvider = buttonAutoPeer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;

// Invoke the default event, which is click for the button

invokeProvider.Invoke();
}
```

Reference:
[Button click programmatically in C# and Xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509908/windows-8-button-click-programmatically-in-c-sharp-and-xaml)